# NotImplementedException in msdeploy when using useChecksum

Tags: c#, runtime-error, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am struggling with msdeploy (AKA web deploy) to deploy applications.

I am using the msdeploy .NET classes, no command line. As soon as I specify the UseCheckSum parameter (whether true or false), it throws me a NotImplementedException.

Here is the stacktrace if any msdeploy developer is around :

```
[NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.]

[DeploymentException: (27.11.2013 11:30:50) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.]
   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.StatusThreadHandler.CheckForException() +67
   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.StatusThreadHandler.Close() +37
   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.RemoteDestSync(DeploymentObject sourceObject, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext, Nullable`1 syncPass) +1966
   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId) +306
   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions) +2692
   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(String provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions) +99
   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentWellKnownProvider provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions) +101
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has acknowledged that this is a bug in version 3.5 (and possibly earlier releases too). The useCheckSum flag is incompatible with other command line arguments, such as setParamFile and verbose.

Details can be found on this page: http://forums.iis.net/t/1184709.aspx?+useChecksum+and+whatif+BUG+.